# Multiple imputation and mlogit for a multinomial regression

Tags: r, statistics, r-mice, mlogit

I am trying to run a multinomial regression with imputed data. I can do this with the nnet package, however I want to use mlogit. Using the mlogit package I keep getting the following error "Error in 1:nrow(data) : argument of length 0".

So making the data

```
library(mlogit)
library(nnet)
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)

df <- data.frame(vax = sample(1:6, 500, replace = T),
                 age = runif(500, 12, 18),
                 var1 = sample(1:2, 500, replace = T),
                 var2 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = T))

# Create missing data using the mice package:
df2 <- ampute(df, prop = 0.15)
df3 <- df2$amp

df3$vax <- as.factor(df3$vax)
df3$var1 <- as.factor(df3$var1)
df3$var2 <- as.factor(df3$var2)

# Inpute missing data:
df4 <- mice(df3, m = 5, print = T, seed = 123)
```

It works using nnet's multinom:

```
multinomtest <- with(df4, multinom(vax ~ age + var1 + var2, data = df, model = T))
summary(pool(multinomtest))
```

But throws up an error when I try to reshape the data into mlogit format

```
test <- with(df4, dfidx(data = df4, choice = "vax", shape = "wide"))
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the imputed data into mlogit format, or even whether mlogit has compatibility with mice or any other imputation package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

You are using `with.mids` incorrectly, and thus both lines of code are wrong; the `multinom` line just doesn't give an error. If you want to apply multiple functions to the imputed datasets, you're better off using something like `lapply`:

```r
analyses <- lapply(seq_len(df4$m), function(i) {
  data.i <- complete(df4, i)
  data.idx <- dfidx(data = data.i, choice = "vax", shape = "wide")
  mlogit(vax ~ 1 | age + var1 + var2, 
         data = data.idx, 
         reflevel = "1", 
         nests = list(type1 = c("1", "2"), type2 = c("3","4"), type3 = c("5","6")))
})
test <- list(call = "", call1 = df4$call, nmis = df4$nmis, analyses = analyses)
oldClass(test) <- c("mira", "matrix")
summary(pool(test))
```

---

**How `with.mids` works**

When you apply `with` to a `mids` object (AKA the output of `mice::mice`), then you are actually calling `with.mids`.

If you use `getAnywhere(with.mids)` (or just type `mice:::with.mids`), you'll find that it does a couple of things:

1. It loops over all imputed datasets.
2. It uses `complete` to get one dataset.
3. It runs the expression with the dataset as the environment.

The third step is the problem. For functions that use formulas (like `lm`, `glm` and `multinom`), you can use that formula within a given environment. If the variables are not in the current environment (but rather in e.g. a data frame), you can specify a new environment by setting the `data` variable.

---

**The problems**

This is where both your problems derive from:

- In your `multinom` call, you set the `data` variable to be `df`. Hence, you are actually running your `multinom` on the original `df`, **NOT** the imputed dataset!
- In your `dfidx` call, you are again filling in `data` directly. This is also wrong. However, leaving it empty also gives an error. This is because `with.mids` doesn't fill in the `data` argument, but only the environment. That isn't sufficient for you.

---

**Fixing `multinom`**

The solution for your `multinom` line is simple: just don't specify `data`:

```r
multinomtest <- with(df4, multinom(vax ~ age + var1 + var2, model = T))
summary(pool(multinomtest))
```

As you will see, this will yield very different results! But it is important to realise that this is what you are trying to obtain.

---

**Fixing dfidx (and mlogit)**

We cannot do this with `with.mids`, since it uses the imputed dataset as the environment, but you want to use the modified dataset (after `dfidx`) as your environment. So, we have to write our own code. You could just do this with any looping function, e.g. `lapply`:

```r
analyses <- lapply(seq_len(df4$m), function(i) {
  data.i <- complete(df4, i)
  data.idx <- dfidx(data = data.i, choice = "vax", shape = "wide")
  mlogit(vax ~ 1 | age + var1 + var2, data = data.idx, reflevel = "1", nests = list(type1 = c("1", "2"), type2 = c("3","4"), type3 = c("5","6")))
})
```

From there, all we have to do is make something that looks like a `mira` object, so that we can still use `pool`:

```r
test <- list(call = "", call1 = df4$call, nmis = df4$nmis, analyses = analyses)
oldClass(test) <- c("mira", "matrix")
summary(pool(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Offering this as a way forward to circumvent the error with `dfidx()`:

```r
df5 <- df4$imp %>% 
  # work with a list, where each top-element is a different imputation run (imp_n)
  map(~as.list(.x)) %>%
  transpose %>%
  # for each run, impute and return the full (imputed) data set
  map(function(imp_n.x) {
    df_out <- df4$data
    df_out$vax[is.na(df_out$vax)] <- imp_n.x$vax
    df_out$age[is.na(df_out$age)] <- imp_n.x$age
    df_out$var1[is.na(df_out$var1)] <- imp_n.x$var1
    df_out$var2[is.na(df_out$var2)] <- imp_n.x$var2
    return(df_out)
  }) %>%
  # No errors with dfidx() now
  map(function(imp_n.x) {
    dfidx(data = imp_n.x, choice = "vax", shape = "wide")
  })
```

However, I'm not too familiar with `mlogit()`, so can't help beyond this.

**Update 8/2/21**

As @slamballais mentioned in their answer, the issue is with dataset you refer to when fitting the model. I assume that `mldata` (from your code in the comments section) is a data.frame? This is probably why you are seeing the same coefficients - you are not referring to the imputed data sets (which I've identified as `imp_n.x` in the functions). The function `purrr::map()` is very similar to `lapply()`, where you apply a function to elements of a list. So to get the code working properly, you would want to change `mldata` to  `imp_n.x`:

```r
# To fit mlogit() for each imputed data set
df5 %>%
  map(function(imp_n.x) {
    # form as specified in the comments
    mlogit(vax ~ 1 | age + var1 + var2, 
           data = imp_n.x, 
           reflevel = "1", 
           nests = list(type1 = c('1', '2'), 
                        type2 = c('3','4'), 
                        type3 = c('5','6')))
  })
```

Comment: @Czechlnk this works. I can add my mlogit formula to it by continuing on the pipe: '%>%
  map(function(imp_n.x) {
    mlogit(vax ~ 1 | age + var1 + var2, data = mldata, reflevel = "1",
           nests = list(type1 = c('1', '2'), type2 = c('3','4'), type3 = c('5','6')))
  })'. My only conern is the output for each imputation is exactly the same, and the same as if I were to run the mlogit on an unimputed dataset. One would expect sligtly different coefficients. I'm not sure exactly what the map(function(imp_n.x) is doing?